# cursor.getString can't equal with string variable

Tags: java, android, android-cursor, getstring

I intend to compare **cursor.getString(1) == pName**, but the code always does the comparison improperly. I was doing anything that came into my mind, but could not make it work. The code is like this :

```
public Cursor addProduct(int id, String pName, int pPrice) {
    int getNewId = 0;
    Cursor cursor = viewProduct();
    if(cursor.getCount() == 0) {
        insertIntoProduct(id, pName, pPrice);
    } else {
        boolean i = false;
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
            if(cursor.getString(1) == pName) {
                i = true;
                getNewId = cursor.getInt(0);
            }
        }
        if(i == true) {
            updateIntoProduct(getNewId, pName, pPrice);
        }
        else {
            insertIntoProduct(id, pName, pPrice);
        }
    }
    return cursor;
}
```

This code works properly except this problem. The cursor will get field of 2 column index, but **cursor.getString(1)** isn't comparing properly with **== pName**.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? What is `viewProduct()`?

Comment: `==` will compare references, not values. why not use `equals()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use == to compare Strings, can you try the following instead:

```
if(cursor.getString(1).equals(pName)) {
    i = true;
    getNewId = cursor.getInt(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, Strings are objects. They might be similar, but when you compare them via the `==` operator, then you are checking whether the two are the exact very same object. Instead of this, you need to compare whether the objects are *similar*, as in

```
if(cursor.getString(1).equals(pName)) {
```